# Communicating Arduino with Intel Galileo

Tags: serial, gsm, arduino-galileo

I'm doing a project where I have few sensors on Arduino Uno. Now I am trying to send some data to the internet where i figured using my GSM shield with the Galileo board I have is the best solution.

The problem I am facing is that software serial is not working on Galileo so I have to use the Serial1 of Galileo board (Pin 0 and Pin 1) and I am out of serial ports. I was thinking of using serial communication between Arduino and Galileo but Galileo seems to have only pin0 and pin1 as serial and they are occupied by the GSM shield.

Is there any part I am getting wrong or any suggestions?

(other than using the sensors on Galileo and getting rid of the Arduino Uno :) )

Comment: What is wrong with getting rid of the UNO and using only the Galileo?

It seems anyway the easier solution even from debugging perspective.

Comment: Well I am using some sensors that has AVR specific libraries and many complex codes depending to them which would be taking much time trying to migrate to Galileo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use SPI/I2C as interface between Arduino and Galileo.
They are better than plain serial.

Comment: I have started using I2C as you suggested. Thank you!